# Variable reassignment within filter-branch command

Tags: git, bash, git-filter-branch

The documentation for [git-filter-branch](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) gives the following snippet:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter \
    'git ls-files -s | sed "s-\t\"*-&newsubdir/-" |
        GIT_INDEX_FILE=$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new \
            git update-index --index-info &&
     mv "$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new" "$GIT_INDEX_FILE"' HEAD
```

but on running it, I always get the following error:

```
mv: cannot stat `/repo/.git-rewrite/t/../index.new': No such file or directory
```

I assume that `git-update-index` references the variable `GIT_INDEX_FILE` to get the location of the index file.  If so, it seems that the snippet is expecting the shell to be able to do something like this:

```
env | MYVAR="home" grep -i $(eval 'echo "$MYVAR"')
```

which does not work (as expected?) in my terminal.  In other words, the assignment `MYVAR=home` seems to have no effect on the subsequent command. Is this something that I can fix through shell options or by modifying the snippet? I have seen this snippet used in various places, including here on SO, so I imagine that there are plenty of people that have been able to get it to work without modification. What am I missing?

- 32-bit cygwin 1.7.30
- git (cygwin) 1.7.9
- bash (cygwin) 4.1.10